# How to solve non-homogeneous Partial Differential Equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

\begin{align}
u_{tt} &= 4u_{xx}+(1-x)\,\cos t, \quad 0 <x < \pi, \quad t>0, \\[1em]
u_x(0,t) &= \cos t - 1, ~\quad u_x(\pi,t) = \cos t, \qquad~~~~~~~~   t \geq 0, \\
u(x,0) &= \frac{x^2 \pi}{2}     ~\quad~~~~~~ u_t(x,0) = \cos(3x),  \quad 0<x<\pi
\end{align}

Using $u(x,t)=w(x,t)+v(x,t)$ I can make the boundary conditions homogenous but I am stumped after that.

Comment: Everytime I read "non-homogeneous pde", I think "Greens functions".

Comment: Need to be used with Eigenfunction Expansion

Comment: try a change of variable $u=v\cos t$

Comment: See this short document on how to expand the source term: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m316/nonhomog.pdf